# Writing program to run on server, requesting experienced advice

Tags: c

I'm developing a program that will need to run on Internet servers (a back-end component to be used by several cross-platform programs). I'm familiar with the security precautions to take (to prevent buffer overflows and SQL Injection attacks, for instance), but have never written a server program before, or any program that will be used on this scale.

The program needs to be able to serve hundreds or thousands of clients simultaneously. The protocols are designed for processing speed and to minimize the amount of data that must be exchanged, and the server side will be written in C. There will be both a Windows and a Linux version from the same code.

Questions:

- How should the program handle communications -- multiple threads, a single thread handling all the sockets in turn, or spawn a new process for every so many incoming connections (or for each one)?
- Do I need to worry about things like memory fragmentation, since this program will need to run for months at a time?
- What other design issues, specific to this kind of programming, might an experienced developer of cross-platform programs for desktop and mobile systems not be aware of?

Please, no suggestions to use a different language. That decision has already been made, for reasons I'm not at liberty to go into.

Comment: Since "this program will need to run for months at a time", it's probably a good idea to also have a *separate* monitoring process to restart your program if it crashes or anything else goes wrong.

Comment: "Not constructive"? It consists of three practical, answerable questions based on an actual problem that I face -- the very definition of a good question, according to the FAQ.

Comment: Your question should also be [reasonably scoped](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: I am quite sure your decision of using plain C instead of C++ is quite wrong for such an application.  I am curious about the details.  

I find it very surprising to still find defenders of standard C for anything else than programming picoprocessors and embedded systems.

Comment: @YaK: What isn't reasonably scoped about the question? I get the feeling that people judged it without reading the question at all.

Comment: @esperanto: Sorry you feel that way. I prefer C++ for almost everything myself, but there are reasons why C is a better option for this program. Unfortunately, as I said in the question, I'm not at liberty to go into them.

Comment: I first thought "this question would likely solicit debate" (definition for "not constructive" questions), this it happens so frequently when the question is of the form "What is the best...?". As a matter of fact, I was wrong, there were none. Then I also somewhat could "imagine an entire book that answers the question" (this is the phrasing of the FAQ). By the look of the answers you were expecting, I was wrong again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my experience running multiple servers for over 3 years of uptime, and programs with little over a year of uptime I can still recommend making the setup so that the system gracefully recovers from a program error and from a server reboot.

Even though performance gets a hit when a program is restarted, you need to be able to handle that as external circumstances can force the program to such a restart.

Don't try to reinvent the wheel when not needed, and have a look at [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) or something like that to handle distribution of incoming communications. (If you are allowed to, prototype the backends in a more forgiving language than C like Python, then reimplement in `C` but keeping the communications protocol)

Comment: Thanks, ZeroMQ seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

For I'd use [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and non-blocking I/O. This way the operating system will take case of most of your scheduling problems. I'd also use a thread pool for processing tasks, that by nature are blocking, so they don't block the main loop. And if you ever need to read or write large amounts of data to or from the disc, use mmap, again to let the OS handle as much as possible.

The basic advice is use the OS, as much as possible. If you want a good example of a program which does this look at [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), it is very well written, and performs fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. libevent (and libev) seem a little lower-level than ZeroMQ (suggested by Anthon), though I may end up using them for other projects.

I'll take a look at Varnish, it sounds like it's designed the way we want this program to work.